# pyscripter for python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyscripter

I have installed Pyscripter 2.5.3 64 bit version in a Win 7 PC. Which python is compatible with this Pyscripter? I tried with several different pythons like 2.7.9 or higher 3.0 (all 64 bit) but everytime I try to run Pyscripter, I get a Quit message.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/PyScripter/jlLqudLj0KQ

there is apparently a new version (now hosted at Sourceforge) http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/ which should try.

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest PyScripter 3.4, install and follow the steps:

```
Run -> Python Versions-> Python 2.7(32 bit)
```

Everything will be according to python 2.7.